# Cell notation for simple voltaic cell

Tags: electrochemistry

We can make a simple voltaic cell consisting of Cu and Zn electrodes dipped in an aqueous H2SO4 solution for demonstration purposes. I am curious to know whether this has a constructible cell notation or not, since I have not come across one in any book so far.

Also, the cell reaction generates H2 gas which makes me doubt that an electric double layer involving H+ ions is formed faster than that involving Cu2+ ions from a Cu electrode. It is also  For the reason that , we see no detectable blue colouration around Cu when the set up - simple cell is in operation. Is that right?

Moreover, does the acidic solution have a liquid junction potential?

Comment: This is simply a variant of the well-known lemon cell, i.e., lemon ‘battery’.

Comment: It is cell Zn/Zn^2+  H+/H2.  Cu acts  as pseudo inert electrode there. Cu^2+ would be reduced first, before H+, but there are no Cu^2+ ions.

Comment: "There are no Cu²+ ions." Does this mean double layer of Cu/ Cu²+ is negligible? It is little unconvincing, because Cu can dissolve in H2SO4 unlike pt/C

Comment: Well...this notation apparently lacks symbols for junction potential/anode cathode separation etc... Is it possible to write like this?